# i got an error when i tried generate signed apk

Tags: java, android

AAPT2 error: check logs for details

in the logs it says:

android:name

```
    ADDED from [com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.37.0] C:\Users\mypc\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\facebook-core-4.37.0.aar\66dcff617fa1bd728075904196dbb822\AndroidManifest.xml:48:25-92</i>
```

so what does it mean? what should i do?

Comment: Why do you think it's an error? It seems it just informs you that the procedure there was running has ADDED the FacebookCore Manifest (and I think it has merged both yours and this one in the final one)

Comment: i can't generate signed apk it says check logs for details but when i checked the log file i see just this notification.